# Index pattern is not showing up in Kibana management

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-7

Using 
`ELK Stack ver 7.3.2`
`Linux RedHat 6.9 (Santiago)`
`Kafka Client 2.1`
Using `kafka-input-plugin` with Logstash.
Kibana is up and running.
Elastic search is configured to run with Kibana.
Kibana is running on the same VM as Elastic search.
Hearbeat is running.
Filebeat is running.
Logstash input is a Kafka topic and is configured to output to Elastic.

I cannot see an index that supposed to be generated by Elastic and put on Kibana.

Here is the simple config for Logstash

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "nydvalkafvm01.tradeware.com:9092"
    topics => ["cat.dev1.service.NJPW7DT004.SM1"]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://nyuatalcasvm01:9200"]
    index => "test_boris"
    workers => 1
    #user => "elastic"
    #password => "changeme"
  }
}
```

Here is the console output

```
[2019-09-20T22:02:00,444][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Revoking previously assigned partitions []
[2019-09-20T22:02:00,445][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] (Re-)joining group
[2019-09-20T22:02:00,506][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2019-09-20T22:02:00,521][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Successfully joined group with generation 13
[2019-09-20T22:02:00,522][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Setting newly assigned partitions [cat.dev1.service.NJPW7DT004.SM1-0, cat.dev1.service.NJPW7DT004.SM1-1]
```

[image]

I expected to see the index 'test_boris' in the Kibana Management 
Is there something I am missing in the config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index won't be created until logstash processes events that end up in the index.  So the root issue is likely that there's nothing coming in from kafka topic.

Comment: I had to create my own topic named boris-topic using kafka console.
 ./kafka-topics.sh -create \
>   --zookeeper localhost:2181 \
>   --replication-factor 1 --partitions 13 \
>   --topic boris-topic
To see my topic I was able query all topics on myhost:9092
./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list myhost:9092 --topic boris-topic
Then I was able to send a message to that topic
>end of the world as we know it